# Copy to next free cell in specific Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy some specific cell to the next empty cell in an other sheet. 
I don't get how to achieve this. Is there someone that can help me?

There are three more ranges that have to get into the other sheet. 
the hole range where to paste `P7:x7` `P10:X10` `P13:T13` (in this order) should be copied to next free Cell at column C starting @ C3
I only need the text inside the cell´s that will be copied

```
function ex1() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var database = ss.getSheetByName("Wochenarchiv");
 var source = ss.getSheetByName('K1');
   var dataToCopy = source.getRange('P7:X7'); // also need P10:X10 and P13:T13
  var copyToSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Wochenarchiv");
    var lastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow();
  for (i = 1; i<11 ;i++){
    var Paste = copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,i).setValues(dataToCopy.getCell(1,i).getValues());
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What are you exactly asking for? Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?

Comment: Welcome. May I try to clarify, please correct me if I'm wrong. You have a spreadsheet with two sheets: "K1" (source) and "Wochenarchiv" (target). On source sheet, you have three ranges: "P7:X7" (9 columns), "P10:X10" (9 columns) and "P13:T13" (5 columns). You want to copy these ranges to Column C of the target sheet, starting at row 3 and continuing at each new blank row. So, "P7:X7" would be copied to "C3:K3", "P10:X10" to "C4:K4", and "P13:T13" to "C5:G5".